# Unable to deploy Firebase Cloud Functions Function didnt deploy properly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to upload 2 functions to Firebase Cloud functions but it always ends up giving an error saying:

***"Error: Functions did not deploy properly."***

When I go to the Firebase Cloud Functions Logs this is the only Info I get:

{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationinfo":{"principalemail":"xxxxxxx@gmail.com"},"servicename":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodname":"google.cloud.functions.v1.cloudfunctionsservice.updatefunction","resourceName":"projects/xxxxxxxxx-ad581/locations/us-central1/functions/newUserSignup"}

Now in here it says there is a bug on my Code but I can't seem to find it:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const randomstring = require("randomstring");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const provid = user.providerData[0].providerId;
  switch (provid) {
    case "facebook.com": {
      let username;
      const tokens = user.displayName.split(" ");
      const nameLength = tokens.length;
      if (nameLength > 1) {
        username = tokens[0] + randomstring.generate(12) + tokens[1];
      } else {
        username = tokens[0] + randomstring.generate(17);
      }
      return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
        "username": username,
        "email": user.email,
        "image_url": user.photoURL,
        "name": user.displayName,
      });
    }
    case "google.com": {
      let username;
      const tokens = user.displayName.split(" ");
      const nameLength = tokens.length;

      if (nameLength > 1) {
        username = tokens[0] + randomstring.generate(12) + tokens[1];
      } else {
        username = tokens[0] + randomstring.generate(17);
      }
      return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
        "username": username,
        "email": user.email,
        "image_url": user.photoURL,
        "name": user.displayName,
      });
    }
    case "apple.com": {
      return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
        "username": null,
        "email": user.email,
        "image_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/647px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png",
        "name": null,
      });
    }
    case "password": {
      return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
        "username": null,
        "email": user.email,
        "image_url": null,
        "name": null,
      });
    }
    default: {
      return;
    }
  }
});

exports.userDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid);
  return doc.delete();
});
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is that with the first Function **newUserSignup** is that when a new user access it gets the ***providerId*** which I save to the variable **provid** and then do a switch where if facebook.com is the provider has some logic, or changes the logic depending on the provider.

On the second Function **userDeleted** I only want to delete the user entry from the the Firestore when the user deleted.

Additional Information

The part of Collection with Double Quotes was requested by ESLint, the randomstring is from a package call RandomString on NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomstring this is to generate a random hash to my usernames. Also the Whole project is already Firebase Init so it has the .firebaserc for the connection.

Any Ideas what the Bug might be?

Kind Regards

Comment: How are your functions being invoked, by http request, or Firebase trigger?

Comment: Firebase Trigger

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what the problem is:

[image: Explorer]

Inside the project, I had 2 node modules in the folder, one outside and one inside the Functions Folder, and I use a node module (RandomString), in the functions, so I needed to add the npm install inside the Functions folder.

Sorry for the question Guys.

Kind Regards.

Comment: did you delete the other node_modules folder? The one outside